# Change the WebDeploy port from 8172 in Azure App service

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, webdeploy

To deploy to a website running in Azure App Service using Visual Studio or Octopus Deploy, I have to be able to make outbound connections from my deployment box on port 8172. However this is blocked by my firewall.

Is there any way to change the port used for WebDeploy in App Service?

Comment: You could configure any firewalls to allow incoming connections on port 8172. Please refer to this [article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-forms/overview/deployment/configuring-server-environments-for-web-deployment/configuring-a-web-server-for-web-deploy-publishing-web-deploy-handler).

Comment: It's a big corporate firewall blocking outbound connections on that port, so would need to configure Azure instead if possible

Comment: In Visual Studio, if you choose App Service as the publish target in your publishing profile, it will use `https://<your site>.scm.azurewebsites.net/msdeploy.axd` to publish your site, rather than WebDeploy. It doesn't require port 8172, but port 443 only.

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by choose app service?  Using the wizard in Vs and clicking the app service still send to be blocked

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, it's not possible to change the web deploy port. This is a configuration of the underlying IIS service which is shared by all users on the same host.

Answer (score 0):

Seems it is not possible so I have swapped to do the deployment with the newer [ZipDeploy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/app-service-deploy-zip#rest) feature and Powershell:

```
$zipDestination = "/file.zip"
$apiUrl = "https://$appServiceName.scm.azurewebsites.net/api/zipdeploy"
$base64AuthInfo = [Convert]::ToBase64String([Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetBytes(("{0}:{1}" -f $siteCredentials.username, $siteCredentials.password)))
$userAgent = "powershell/1.0"

Write-Host "POSTing $zipDestination to $apiUrl as user $($siteCredentials.username)"

try {
    Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $apiUrl -Headers @{Authorization=("Basic {0}" -f $base64AuthInfo)} -UserAgent $userAgent -Method POST -InFile $zipDestination -ContentType "multipart/form-data"
    Write-Host "Publish complete"
} catch {
    Write-Host "Publish failed"

    # Note that value__ is not a typo.
    Write-Host "StatusCode:" $_.Exception.Response.StatusCode.value__ 
    Write-Host "StatusDescription:" $_.Exception.Response.StatusDescription

    Throw $_.Exception
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried both with WEBSITES_PORT and PORT and both with code from repository through github actions and a docker image from dockerhub (with "EXPOSE 8000" working locally).
Azure wraps your applications and expose only port 80 and 443.
In my case I got:
github actions --> port 80 and HTTP
docker image --> port 443 and HTTPS